# How do i find the height of recyclerView item (tableRow in my case)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which i need to use in a cardView (cardView is further  a child of scrollView) and i want to set the height of recyclerView is equal as of number of rows in recyclerView * height of one row.

Here is my xml of activity:

```
<NestedScrollView ...>
     <....other cardViews >
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

           // heading of cardview {
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_boder"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/search_details_email"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:text="Job Completion Summary"
                    android:textColor="@color/customerColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/line_color" />
              // heading end }

              // table start
                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Tablelayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                   // table header only {
                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="14dp"
                            android:text="Technician"
                            android:textSize="18sp"

                            />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/line_color" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="14dp"
                            android:text="CL"
                            android:textSize="18sp"

                            />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/line_color" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="14dp"
                            android:text="OS"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/line_color" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="14dp"
                            android:text="LS"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/line_color" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="14dp"
                            android:text="CO"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </TableRow>
                   //  table header end }

                   // rows below header created by recyclerView
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/technicianRecycleListView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

          <... other views />
 </NestedScrollView>
```

and here is my recyclerView item's xml:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/technicianName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="Technician"
        android:textSize="18sp"

        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/line_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ci"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="CL"
        android:textSize="18sp"

        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/line_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/os"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="OS"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/line_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="LS"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/line_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/co"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="CO"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</TableRow>
```

Now I want to get the height of recyclerView item's layout, so that i can calculate the exact height of recyclerView before calling setAdaper of recyclerView. So that it will scroll with NestedScrollView. Anyone know? How can i do this?

I have tried to get the textView height but it is always return 0;

Answer (score 2):

You can't know the height of a view before it's been fully inflated and all of its data has been populated and gone through its final layout pass.  If you need to know the height of a view before it's been inflated, you should fix the height of the view and make sure its backing data can never force that height to change (for example, by setting the max number of lines in a TextView, ellipsizing strings, and cropping and fitting images).